# Partial fraction decomposition for $\int\frac{3x^3+1}{x^3-x^2+x-1}dx$

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

I have been at this for hours and I don't know what I am doing wrong. It's partial fraction decomposition that I am doing but I just can't seem to get what I am supposed to

$$\int\frac{3x^3+1}{x^3-x^2+x-1}dx$$

so the bottom would be

$x^2(x-1)+(x-1)$ which turns into $(x-1)(x^2+1)$

then I separate by

$$\frac{a}{x-1}+\frac{bx+c}{x^2+1}$$

I then got

$$a(x^2+1)+(bx+c)(x-1)$$

$$ax^2+a+bx^2-bx+cx-c$$

it would mean that $a+b=0$ and $-b+c=0$ and $a-c=1$

I got, $a=1/2$ $b=-1/2$ and $c=-1/2$

Did I solve my A right?

My final answer ended up being $$\frac{1}{2}\ln(x-1)-\frac{1}{4}\ln \left|x^2+1\right|-\frac{1}{2}\arctan \left(x\right)+C$$

It's just that when I take the derivative of my answer, it's just 1 as the numerator as opposed to $3x^3+1$

Comment: The numerator is $3x^2+1$ (in the title) or $3x^3+1$ (in the body)?

Comment: In the body. Sorry again. I've been up all night with this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int\frac{3x^3+1}{x^3-x^2+x-1}dx$$
To evaluate this, we have to split the function into partial fraction.
\begin{align*}
&\frac{3x^3+1}{x^3-x^2+x-1} = A + \frac{B}{x-1} + \frac{Cx + D}{x^2 + 1}\\
\implies &3x^3 + 1 = A(x^3 - x^2 + x - 1) + B(x^2 + 1) + (Cx + D)(x-1)\\
\implies & 3x^3 +1 = Ax^3 - Ax^2 + Ax - A + Bx^2 + B + Cx^2 - Cx + Dx - D\\
\implies & 3x^3 +1 = Ax^3 + (C-A + B)x^2 + (A-C+D)x - A + B - D
\end{align*}
Comparing coefficients, we obtain:
\begin{align*}
A &= 3\\
C-A+B &= 0\\
A-C+D &= 0\\
B-A-D &= 1
\end{align*}
Since $A = 3$, we have that $$C + B = 3$$
$$D-C = -3$$
$$B-D = 4$$
From the third equation, $B = 4 + D$. Substituting this value into the first equation, we obtain$$C + D = -1$$
Solving
\begin{align*}
D + C &= -1\\
D - C &= -3
\end{align*}
we obtain $2D = -4 \implies D = -2, C = 1$. Also, $B = 4 + D \implies B = 2$.

Hence, $A = 3, B = 2, C = 1, D = -2$ $$\implies \frac{3x^3+1}{x^3-x^2+x-1} = 3 + \frac{2}{x-1} + \frac{x-2}{x^2+1}$$

$$
\therefore \int\frac{3x^3+1}{x^3-x^2+x-1} = \int \left[3 + \frac{2}{x-1} + \frac{x-2}{x^2+1}\right]dx$$

$$
= 3x + 2ln(x-1) + \frac{1}{2}ln(x^2+1) - 2tan^{-1}x$$

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

As $$x^3-x^2+x-1=(x^2+1)(x-1)$$

the partial fraction should be $$\dfrac A{x-1}+\dfrac{Bx+C}{x^2+1}$$

Comment: It was a typo so I did do that on my paper, so I don't think that was the mistake I made.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the degree of both the numerator and the denominator is $3$. So, you cannot use partial fractions at that moment.

Noting that
$$3x^3+1=3x^3-3x^2+3x-3+3x^2-3x+3+1=3(x^3-x^2+x-1)+3x^2-3x+4$$
you can write
$$\frac{3x^3+1}{x^3-x^2+x-1}=3+\frac{3x^2-3x+4}{x^3-x^2+x-1}$$
then find $a,b,c$ such that
$$\frac{3x^2-3x+4}{x^3-x^2+x-1}=\frac{a}{x-1}+\frac{bx+c}{x^2+1}$$

Comment: How is that helping can you explain

Comment: @ArchisWelankar: I added a bit. Better?

Comment: Hmm now i got it +1

Answer (score 0):

Hint: (x+1)(x^3-x^2+x-1) = x^4 + 1